# Find for each calendar date if it is included between start and end date of bookings

Tags: date, google-sheets-formula, google-calendar-api

I've been stuck for days now trying to figure out how to do the following formula.  I have looked through youtube videos, blogs, forums and cannot solve this one.

For each calendar date in my table, I want to identify if that date is available or booked when looking at all my event list that have a booked status:

```
IF "CALENDAR_DATE" 
ISBETWEEN "EVENT_START_DATE" AND "EVENT_END_DATE" 
OF ANY EVENTS 
WHERE THE "STATUS" = "Booked" 
THEN RETURN "TRUE" in the "Booked" column.  
OTHERWISE  return "TRUE" in the "Available" column
```

**Extra Question:** Anybody knows a component, app, widget that could read my google sheet and present calendar availabilities on a website

[image: Google Sheet Image]

**You can access my Google Sheet here:**
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zMUfGy1aU3-J_-NFKYy6X309oo63j0nss1x-QXWf9l8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Are you doing this only though google sheets?  This question doesnt seem to be programing related to me.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=LAMBDA(G, H, I, INDEX(IF(A2:A="",,""<>IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A, 
 QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(DAYS(H, G)+1<=SEQUENCE(1, MAX(DAYS(H, G)), 0),,
 G+SEQUENCE(1, MAX(DAYS(H, G)), 0)&"​"&I)), "​"), 
 "select Col1,max(Col1) where Col2 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col2"), 
 {2, 3}, )))))(G2:G5, H2:H5, I2:I5)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi player0, First, thanks for attempting to solve this challenge.  It's not an easy one (at least for me).  I tried your formula.  It works in part but not for all of them.  I placed the formula in cell B2 and made my google sheet editable by anyone so you can see the results and where the formula does not work.  But you are so close to solving it all! https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zMUfGy1aU3-J_-NFKYy6X309oo63j0nss1x-QXWf9l8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @LouisGaulin year in H2 is 2020. should be 2022

Answer (score 0):

Use this formula in cell B2 and copy to the rest of column B:

```
=COUNT(FILTER(F$2:F,A2>=G$2:G,A2<H$2:H,I$2:I="Booked"))>0
```

What it does:
The FILTER function gets an interval (in this case, column F, starting from F2) and populates it based in conditions that come from other columns with the same size. So it returns all lines where G<something> <= A2 < H<something> and I<something> = "Booked". Then, we count if there was at least one result. This results in TRUE or FALSE, marking the checkbox if TRUE.

In cell C2, use this formula and copy to the rest of the column:

```
=NOT(B2)
```

About your extra question: you can use Google Forms and the [FormRanger add-on](https://workspace.google.com/marketplace/app/form_ranger/387838027286). But it will show the options in components like combobox or radio button, I don't know how to show a calendar.
Anyway, I hope this helps. :)